# Call to undefined function where() laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I'm passing some data from JS to PHP through Ajax and I'm using the data to retrieve information from my database using a query but I'm getting an error: **Call to undefined function  where() on -where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$Debut)
                ->where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',"<",$Fin)**

Here's my code :

```
 public function Calculer( Request $request )

{

    if(isset($request))
    {
        $marque = $request->get('marque');
        $modele = $request->get('modele');
        $finition = $request->get('finition');
        $Debut = $request->get('Debut');
        $Fin =$request ->get('Fin');
        $Debut=strtotime($Debut);
        $Fin=strtotime($Fin);


        $TotalAproduire = 100;

        $Commande = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Commande_nadine')
            ->join('finition','Commande_nadine.CodeFinition','=','finition.CodeFinition')
            ->where('finition.CodeFinition',"=",$finition)
            ->where('finition.CodeModele','=',$modele)
            -where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$Debut)
            ->where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',"<",$Fin)
            ->where('finition.CodeMarque','=',$marque)
            ->count('Commande_nadine.RECID_NADIN');
        $PourcentageCommandee=($Commande/$TotalAproduire)*1000;

        return $PourcentageCommandee ;



    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
    }

}
```

Can you help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
-where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$Debut)
```

You are missing a `>` before `where`:

```
->where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$Debut)
```